# Typescript check generic type for interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In my angular 6 file I've got an interface defined and then in a method that takes a generic parameter, T, I want to determine if T implements that interface at runtime.  Is that possible?

I tried to do `if (T instanceof INetworkObject)` but the compiler doesn't like that.

```js
export interface INetworkObject {
    fixNetworkObject(): void;
}

protected getTypedItem<T>(endpoint: string, C: { new(): T }): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(`${this.baseUrl}/${endpoint}`)
        .pipe(map(element => {
            if (!element) {
                return null;
            }

            const ret = Object.assign(new C(), element);

            if (T.type instanceof NetworkObject) {

            }

            // This ugliness is what I'm doing now
            if (typeof ret['fixNetworkObject'] === 'function') {
                ret['fixNetworkObject']();
            }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is call `fixNetworkObject` on `ret` if it implements that interface.

Comment: @IngoBürk I'm familiar with most of those, but the fact that it's a generic is what's causing me issues.  T won't *always* implement NetworkObject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use `instanceof` because interfaces don't exist at runtime. You need to declare a type guard like so (see the [Advanced Types Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)):

```
function isINetworkObject(obj: any): obj is INetworkObject {
  return typeof obj.fixNetworkObject === 'function';
}
```

Then modify your if:

```
if (isINetworkObkect(ret)) {
  ret.fixNetworkObject();
}
```

Comment: That assumes that T *always* extends Lengthwise.  I don't know that here.  Sometimes it will, sometimes it won't.

Comment: I don't think so, because `Fish` there is the interface, right?  I don't *always* have something of that type.  That's why I need it as a runtime check.

Comment: So I see how that determines if it is that class or not.  But how does `ret` there, which is a generic type, know that it can call fixNetworkObject().  Seems like that should be a typescript build error!

Comment: That is how the type guard works. The special `is` return type means that the function below will check for type safety however the user deems safe. If the function returns true then the argument specified `is` the type in question. Then if you have an `if` that depends on these `is` types it applies the type safety of the variable to the code block of the `if` (or `else` if you did an inverse or something).

Comment: It is also smart enough to handle returns, so you can do something like this: `if (!isINetworkObkect(ret)) return;` and all of the code in the function below would use the type.